# How to draw a CLLocationCoordinate2Ds on MKMapSnapshotter (drawing on mapView printed image)

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapsnapshotter

I have mapView with array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. I use these locations to draw lines on my mapView by using `MKPolyline`. Now i want to store it as a UIimage. I found that theres class `MKMapSnapshotter` but unfortunately i can't draw overlays on it "Snapshotter objects do not capture the visual representations of any overlays or annotations that your app creates." So i get only blank map image. Is there any way to get image with my overlays?

```
private func generateImageFromMap() {
    let mapSnapshotterOptions = MKMapSnapshotter.Options()
    guard let region = mapRegion() else { return }
    mapSnapshotterOptions.region = region
    mapSnapshotterOptions.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
    mapSnapshotterOptions.showsBuildings = false
    mapSnapshotterOptions.showsPointsOfInterest = false


    let snapShotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: mapSnapshotterOptions)
    snapShotter.start() { snapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
//do something with image .... 
            let mapImage = snapshot...
        }
    }
}
```

How can i put overlays on this image? Or maybe theres other way for that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to draw them yourself. Fortunately, `MKSnapshot` has a convenient [`point(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapsnapshotter/snapshot/1452523-point) method to convert a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` into a `CGPoint` within the snapshot.

For example, assume you had an array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`:

```
private var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]?

private func generateImageFromMap() {
    guard let region = mapRegion() else { return }

    let options = MKMapSnapshotter.Options()
    options.region = region
    options.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
    options.showsBuildings = false
    options.showsPointsOfInterest = false

    MKMapSnapshotter(options: options).start() { snapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }

        let mapImage = snapshot.image

        let finalImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: mapImage.size).image { _ in

            // draw the map image

            mapImage.draw(at: .zero)

            // only bother with the following if we have a path with two or more coordinates

            guard let coordinates = self.coordinates, coordinates.count > 1 else { return }

            // convert the `[CLLocationCoordinate2D]` into a `[CGPoint]`

            let points = coordinates.map { coordinate in
                snapshot.point(for: coordinate)
            }

            // build a bezier path using that `[CGPoint]`

            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.move(to: points[0])

            for point in points.dropFirst() {
                path.addLine(to: point)
            }

            // stroke it

            path.lineWidth = 1
            UIColor.blue.setStroke()
            path.stroke()
        }

        // do something with finalImage
    }
}
```

Then the following map view (with the coordinates, as `MKPolyline`, rendered by `mapView(_:rendererFor:)`, like usual):

[image]

The above code will create the this `finalImage`:

[image]

Comment: No idea why but didint work with private var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]? for me.I couldnt append any 2Ccoordinates to this array. I change it to var coord2d: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [] and changed guard let to   let coordinates = self.coord2d
                if self.coord2d.count > 1 {
                    
                } else {
                    return
                }. And it works perfectly! Thats what i was looking for

Comment: No problem. I’m glad this solved your issue. FWIW, the use of that private variable is unrelated to the question here. Clearly, I assumed you’d use your own, existing array of coordinates. But you didn’t share how those coordinates were stored in your code, so I had to use something, and I had no way of knowing what you called your array. Lol.